# Iteration not working in Lambda as I want to run lambda in two regions listed in code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Hi I have this simple lambda function which stops all EC-2 instances tagged with Auto_off. I have set a for loop so that it works for two regions us-east-1 and us-east-2. I am running the function in us-east-2 region.

the problem is that only the instance located in us-east2 is stopping and the other instance is not(located in us-east-1). what modifications can i make.

please suggest as i am new to python and boto library

```
import boto3
import logging

#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#define the connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')

ec2_regions = ['us-east-1','us-east-2']

for region in ec2_regions:
conn = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
# Use the filter() method of the instances collection to retrieve
# all running EC2 instances.
filters = [{
        'Name': 'tag:AutoOff',
        'Values': ['True']
    },
    {
        'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
        'Values': ['running']
    }
]

#filter the instances
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

#locate all running instances
RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

#print the instances for logging purposes
#print RunningInstances 

#make sure there are actually instances to shut down. 
if len(RunningInstances) > 0:
    #perform the shutdown
    shuttingDown = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=RunningInstances).stop()
    print shuttingDown
else:
    print "Nothing to see here"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating 2 instances of ec2 resource, and 1 instance of ec2 client. You are only using one instance of ec2 resource, and not using the client at all. You are also setting the region in your loop on a different resource object from the one you are actually using.

Change all of this:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')

ec2_regions = ['us-east-1','us-east-2']

for region in ec2_regions:
conn = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
```

To this:

```
ec2_regions = ['us-east-1','us-east-2']
for region in ec2_regions:
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
```

Also your indentation is all wrong in the code in your question. I hope that's just a copy/paste issue and not how your code is really indented, because indentation is syntax in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The loop you do here

```
ec2_regions = ['us-east-1','us-east-2']
for region in ec2_regions:
    conn = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
```

Firstly assigns `us-east-1` to the `conn` variable and on the second step, it overwrites it with `us-east-2` and then it enters your function.

So what you can do is put that loop inside your function and do the current definition of the function inside that loop.